# Can I create a definition list with markdown for doxygen?

Tags: list, format, markdown, doxygen, list-definition

I'd like to create a "definition list" format like the following (I can't figure out how to format this so StackOverflow displays it as I intend. I do not mean the resulting text should be preformatted or a code block):

```
Term A

    This is the definition of Term A. It can be multi-line and wrap.

Term B

    This is the definition of Term B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Basic markdown does not support definition lists, and as per doxygen's set of list extensions ([here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#mddox_lists)), doxygen doesn't add it.

Comment: I thought that's what I would hear. Thanks for confirming!